# Intersection point of two wires

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

When I observe two thin wires (up to 1cm, relatively) at a distance, if those two wires are intersecting (but may or may not have physical contact) the absolute point of their intersection is invisible, like you're viewing through the intersection.

For example, when you see the point of intersection two telephone cables from erected poles, you don't see a cross but the sky beyond it. This gap is especially large if the angle between the intersecting wires is very small.

Is this due to diffraction? How does diffraction occur in this case?

Comment: Not clear what you mean -> Photo, or drawing ? ( I generaly see the opposite : exagerated occlusion around the intersection )

Comment: Neither. Just on seeing.

Comment: If you see this, a photo should likely reproduce this.  Can post an example?  I don't recall observing this.